# Cross Reference Text from another sheet and display match in adjacent cell

Tags: vba, excel

I am using Excel 2010 and have a table of actions on Sheet 1 as follows:

```
**Actions**
Normal - No Action
Satifactory - No Action Required
Contact - Repeat In
Contact - Arrange Telecon With
Appointment Already Made
Ask Reception To
Already Dealt With
Letter Required
```

I then have an imported list of these actions assigned to people on Sheet 2 as shown below in column A, but some of the actions may include additional free text added to the end of each action (which I have highlighted only in this example between the asterisks):

```
**ACTION LIST**
Contact - Arrange Telecon With *ABCD*
Contact - Arrange Telecon With *efgh*
Appointment Already Made *17/07/2016*
Appointment Already Made *15/08/16*
Contact - Repeat In *2w*
Contact - Repeat In *3m*
Contact - Repeat In *1y*
Contact - Repeat In *6m*
Ask Reception To *Blah Blah*
Ask Reception To *Blah Blah Blah*
Satisfactory - No Action Required
```

I need to count up how many actions there are in the list above EXCLUDING the additional free text that has been added to some of the actions, so that the outcome would look like this in the adjacent cell i.e. column B:

```
**Action Outcome for Counting**
Contact - Arrange Telecon With
Contact - Arrange Telecon With
Appointment Already Made
Appointment Already Made
Contact - Repeat In
Contact - Repeat In
Contact - Repeat In
Contact - Repeat In
Ask Reception To
Ask Reception To
Satifactory - No Action Required
```

Is there an Excel formula I can use to create the last table of text?
Can a formula match the text of the actions in the 1st table to that of the 2nd table.
Note: The Action text in the 2nd table will always begin with the text from the 1st table, the additional freetext is always added to the end of an Action.

I need to count how many actions (in the 1st table) have been used in the 2nd table?

Comment: I posted an answer but decided to delete it as I'm not sure it covers your requirement. It's a countif with a wild card e.g. =countif(a:a, b2 & "*"). It will count all occurrences of an action even if it contains any trailing characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an Array form of INDEX/MATCH with Search to compare the substrings:

```
=INDEX($E$1:$E$8,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH( $E$1:$E$8,A1)),0))
```

My list of Actions is in column E.

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when leaving edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.

Comment: Could I also ask how you got that image of Excel in the comments?

Comment: @BradleyS once you get past 50 rep points you can post pictures.  But you should always post the data like you did when asking a question, so we can copy and past the data to test.